# Drupal 7: Add a rel attribute to image field link

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I add a `rel` attribute to an image field's link? I'm not sure if there's a tpl.php that I can use or if there's something I can place in my template.php that will do it. I've tried the code from this page but I'm not sure where I would place the `rel` attribute :(

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7

Comment: Where do you want to assign the value of your rel attribute? Is it a field part of a content type ?

Comment: I'd like to assign it in a template file. I don't want my admin users to have to type in a rel value on all of the images that get uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preprocess` hook of an image to add attributes on the HTML `<img>` tag.

Here is an example by implementing it in the `template.php` of your theme:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables)
{
    $variables['attributes'] = array(
        'rel' => 'the-rel-value',
    );
}
```